# NIntegrate Error

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to solve this expression with the function NIntegrate:

```
    NIntegrate[(2Subscript[b, 2])/(0.72*2\[Pi]^2*8.85418782*10^-12*3^2) (NIntegrate[( [Delta]*
    (3.482+\[Delta])EllipticE[-((4*0.1516*Subscript[b, 2])/((3.482+\[Delta])^2+
    (0.1516-Subscript[b, 2])^2))])/(((3.482+\[Delta])^2+(0.1516+Subscript[b, 2])^2)*
    Sqrt[(3.482+\[Delta])^2+(0.1516-Subscript[b, 2])^2]),{\[Delta],-0.36,0.36}]),{Subscript[b, 2],0,3}]
```

However, when I try to solve it gives me 3 of this error:

```
    NIntegrate::inumr: "The integrand (\[Delta]\(3.482 +\[Delta])\EllipticE[-((0.6064 
    Subscript[b, 2])/((3.482 +\[Delta])^2+(<<1>>)^2))])/(Sqrt[(3.482 +\[Delta])^2+
    (0.1516 -Subscript[b, 2])^2]\((3.482 +\[Delta])^2+(0.1516 +Subscript[b, 2])^2)) " has
    evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the
    region with boundaries {{-0.36,0.}}
```

By the way it gives the approximate value of my input but I wonder why it gives me these errors. Is it affecting the output? Thnaks.

Comment: You should comment on the answers you receive. If they are right, you should upvote/accept. If they are wrong you should explain why

Answer (score 1):

Your inner `NIntegrate[]` argument is of course non numeric because it depends on the outer `NIntegrate[]` variables. So,

```
f[d_, b_] := ((3.482 + d)^2 + (0.1516 - b)^2); 
NIntegrate[2 b ((d*(3.482 + d) EllipticE[-((4 0.1516 b)/f[d, b])])/(f[d, b] Sqrt[f[d, b]])), 
           {d, -0.36, 0.36}, {b, 0, 3}]

 (* -0.0103908 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Quiet to silence the error warnings

```
NIntegrate[
  2 b2/(0.72*2 \[Pi]^2*8.85418782*10^-12*3^2) (NIntegrate[(d*(3.482 + 
          d) EllipticE[-(4*0.1516*
            b2/((3.482 + d)^2 + (0.1516 - b2)^2))])/(((3.482 + 
             d)^2 + (0.1516 + b2)^2)*
        Sqrt[(3.482 + d)^2 + (0.1516 - b2)^2]), {d, -0.36, 0.36}]), {b2, 0, 
   3}] // Quiet
```

> -8.01331*10^6

or separate out the inner NIntegrate and define it for only numeric arguments

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[(d*(3.482 + 
        d) EllipticE[-(4*0.1516*
          x/((3.482 + d)^2 + (0.1516 - x)^2))])/(((3.482 + d)^2 + (0.1516 + 
           x)^2)*Sqrt[(3.482 + d)^2 + (0.1516 - x)^2]), {d, -0.36, 0.36}];

NIntegrate[2 b2/(0.72*2 \[Pi]^2*8.85418782*10^-12*3^2) f[b2], {b2, 0, 3}]
```

> -8.01331*10^6